# Facing this error in Pytest on selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, class, automation, pytest

```
import time
import self as self
from pytest import mark
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from setuptools import setup
@mark.execute
class First_Tests:

    def test_first(self, setup):
        driver = setup['driver']
        browser = setup['browser']
        driver.get("https://shuftipro.com/")
        driver.maximize_window()

    def header_test(self, setup):
        driver = setup['driver']

        # Click on solution in header
        solution = driver.find_element(By.ID, "menu-item-72751")
        solution.click()
        if driver.current_url == "https://shuftipro.com/solutions/":
            print("land on solution page.")
        else:
            print("land on wrong page.")
obj = First_Tests()
obj.test_first(self, setup)
obj.header_test(self, setup)
```

If I remove the "self" from parameter and run the program it showing me error that, test_first() takes 1 positional arguments but 3 were given

Answer (score 1):

one of easier way would be to use webdriver from selenium

`driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

and remove

```
driver = setup['driver']
browser = setup['browser']
```

and then get rid of setup as parameter.
The final code will look something like this:

```
from pytest import mark
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
@mark.execute
class First_Tests:

    def test_first(self):
        driver.get("https://shuftipro.com/")
        driver.maximize_window()

    def header_test(self):
        # Click on solution in header
        solution = driver.find_element(By.ID, "menu-item-72751")
        solution.click()
        if driver.current_url == "https://shuftipro.com/solutions/":
            print("land on solution page.")
        else:
            print("land on wrong page.")

obj = First_Tests()
obj.test_first()
obj.header_test()
```